# How to manipulate this array

Tags: php, arrays

I want figure out how can I manipulate this array. Here is my example :

```
$color = "red,yellow,green,black";
$stock = "10,20,30,40";
```

If user chooses yellow and a quantity of 5, then stock of the item with color yellow becomes 15.

My question is, how to change stock item with yellow color become like this :

```
$color = "red,yellow,green,black";
$stock = "10,15,30,40";
```

What I think is, I get an array position where color is yellow and it will return 1. And update stock where array position is 1. But I don't have idea how to do that. Can anybody give me a suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, you can modify it to suit you. This assumes your strings would transform into arrays of the same size and that the order will be correct

```
// transform $color to array using comma as delimiter and return key position for yellow
$position = array_search('yellow', explode(',', $color));
// transform $stock to array
$stock = explode(',', $stock);
// change value at the same position
$stock[$position] = 15;
// put it back into string
$stock = implode(',', $stock);
echo $stock;
```

You could also store your data in a single array using key -> value pairs, in which case manipulating it would be trivial.

Comment: it returns `10,15,30,40` using variables you posted above

Comment: thx marko, i make a mistake. I write stock with stok, so it return false. Thx, it's work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Those are not arrays, but strings. You should become familiar with [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) first.

You can transform your strings to arrays using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: ...and turn the arrays back into strings with `implode`.